# MSBuild project vs PowerShell build procedure

Tags: .net, powershell, build, msbuild

I have to complete the following tasks:

- Prebuild setup (download dependencies etc.)
- Build .net solution
- Run Tests (unit tests and functional tests)
- Generate documentation
- Generate nuget packages
- Sign output

I'm able to complete the task by creating PS build procedure(that uses msbuild just to compile the solution) or MSBuild project with targets(that uses some helper PS scripts). PowerShell is more flexible but MSBuild is a build framework an has some integrated build related features. **I'm wondering what will be the best approach.** Please share thoughts.

Comment: The question is probably too broad. But you may be interested in some build automation tools in PowerShell like [Invoke-Build](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build). Here is the [Tutorial](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build/wiki/Script-Tutorial) to get familiar quickly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can use some of the patterns there if I go with PowerShell. I'm familiar with PS and new to MSBuild. I'm just wondering if MSBuild can provide some out of the box functionality that is hard to implement in PS.

Comment: Probably. Invoke-Build is just a task runner, powerful due to PowerShell. But real build utilities are all external. Fortunately, they are easy to call from Invoke-Build scripts, e.g. `exec { MSBuild .... }`.

Comment: Maybe `cake` could help you out -> see http://cakebuild.net/.

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box, **MSBuild** is specialized in handling tasks and its dependencies. So when you want to do custom stuff that MSBuild can't do by default, you need to call scripts/tools through targets or you can add more types of tasks by including community/custom extensions to your project.

On the other hand, **Powershell** is free of form, so you have to work your way without built-in structure, but you have the liberty to do whatever you want right out of the box and without having to use another tool/language to fill up the gaps. **For multiple projects**, you'll have to create some sort of framework if you want to keep your build system maintainable.

**If you want both worlds**, **[PSAKE](https://github.com/psake/psake)** is a tasks handling Powershell module that acts similarly to MSBuild and has syntax based on RAKE, which is pretty neat. In short, PSAKE have a lighter syntax than MSBuild and has most of its features available through Powershell, so you benefit from both worlds.

**Generally, it's a matter of taste and needs**. I favor short and sweet syntax that tells clearly what part of code do what. MSBuild is based on XML, so there is a lot of redundancy, it has no IDE shipped with it and needs an external tool like Visual Studio to debug it. PSAKE is a Powershell module, so you can spawn Powershell ISE, load the module and enjoy IntelliSense while creating your build scripts.

But understand that there is a lot of possibilities as of what to choose, so pick your poison and **don't narrow your choices to only MSBuild and Powershell**. **[See some alternatives here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software)**

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild (Now we have a wrapper using dotnet cli) is the Microsoft build engine, its goal is to create a set of task to finally get artifacts or assemblies. 
On the other hand PowerShell is a task automation and configuration management. It means you can create scripts for more complex pipelines including Calling a MSBuild,NuGet CLI and so on (e.g. calling Remote modules or any other additional tasks).